# Corona object to mirror attribute of another

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Using corona, I have an image that is transitioning to a new x / y location due to a collision (using the physics module).

I would like a 2nd image, a shadow image, to follow this first image.  I will need to scale the shadow and move it's y coordinate.

How can I get the 2nd object to mirror the 1st object as it moves?

... the following actually appears to work fine, but I would think it is not the most efficient.  Would be interested in any further thoughts?

```
local function onGlobalPostCollision( event )
    shadowImageOne.x = tabImageOne.x
    shadowImageTwo.x = tabImageTwo.x
    shadowImageThree.x = tabImageThree.x
end

Runtime:addEventListener( "postCollision", onGlobalPostCollision )
```

Answer (score 0):

Three ways, essentially:

#### Use a reference

If you store the position as a table, like:

```
position = [x, y]
```

then just setting it by reference will do.

#### Copy manually each frame

Straightforward. On every iteration of the update routine, set the graphics sprite position to the physical position

#### Stateless render

Make your rendering stateless. Make it take a full program state each time and draw based on that. No updates necessary if there's no state kept.

---

In general, I would personally avoid keeping state in display objects. It makes it harder to test the logic separately and creates issues like that. Stateless render gives you a guarantee of sync; hovewer, it might incur some performance penalties if graphics require intensive caching (you don't want to be recreating all sprites each time if that's costly).

Comment: thanks Bartek.  Just to clarify though the movement is due to a collision so I dont know where the final x and y will end up.  I believe that eliminates option 1 "use a reference"?

Comment: @AlanPower if by saying "I dont know where the final x and y will end up" you mean you don't know the *values*, that's the point - if you store a table, it isn't copied. Updating one reference (held by physics) will also impact all reads done by graphics. I can do an example if you want.

Comment: Thanks Bartek... if you have an example that would be great.  I have the following working, but I dont think it's the most efficient:      local function onGlobalPostCollision( event )
    shadowImageOne.x = tabImageOne.x
end

Runtime:addEventListener( "postCollision", onGlobalPostCollision )